# Attach a file to an input with javascript

Tags: javascript, html

I have an input to upload files

```
<input type="file" name="comment[video_file]" id="comment_video_file">
```

Is it possible to attach a file by JavaScript?

I have tried but it didn't work

```
    let file = new File([videoBlob], "video.mp4", { type: "video/mp4" });
    let element = document.getElementById("comment_video_file");
    element.append("video", video);
```

If I console log the element after the append it looks like this

```
<input type="file" name="comment[video_file]" id="comment_video_file">
  "video"
  "[object File]"
</input>
```

Comment: The `files` property on an input is a read only property, as far as I am aware.

Comment: You can't do this, the input can only contain files selected directly by the user themselves, from the file system on their computer/device. If you need to upload this blob then you can do that with JavaScript, but not via this method

Comment: So, I can't attach it to the input or the form? How can I do it?

Comment: "So, I can't attach it to the input or the form? How can I do it?" As previously stated **YOU CAN'T**. It's a security restriction. The file(s) have to be selected by the user.

Comment: "How can I do it?" ...usually by sending the data via AJAX within a FormData object. A little bit of your own research would help you discover this, and discover some examples.

Answer (score 3):

It isn't possible to create a file and attach it to an HTML form input but using the FormData object you could send a generated file to the server as part of a post request.

Pulled from the MDN:

```
var formData = new FormData();

// JavaScript file-like object
var content = '<a id="a"><b id="b">hey!</b></a>'; // the body of the new file...
var blob = new Blob([content], { type: "text/xml"});

formData.append("webmasterfile", blob);

var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("POST", "http://example.com/submitform.php");
request.send(formData);
```

Which should get you the same result of a file generated by JS sent to the server.

Answer (score 0):

MDN article [on file inputs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file) states:

> You can set as well as get the value of `HTMLInputElement.files` in all modern browsers; this was most recently added to Firefox, in version 57

I tried setting `input.files` to a `files` property from a [drag-n-drop files event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/DataTransfer/files) and it worked. Though I'm not sure if it's possible to do it with a manually created File.

If this won't work, try sending an XMLHttpRequest with FormData with a file Blob, as advised in other answers/comments.